# How to override Windows' convert command by ImageMagick's one?

Tags: windows, imagemagick

In **Windows**, a command called `convert` is used to convert the filesystems. When you type `convert`, it will ask you to specify a filesystem.

In **ImageMagick**, `convert` command is used for image processing.

The problem is, even after setting the environment variable for ImageMagick `convert`, the tool doesn't get invoked. It calls only the Windows `convert` command. How to override that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you logoff and login?

Or specify the Imagemagick's convert by providing the complete path

Comment: Thank u . Is there any way other providing complete path ?

Comment: Did you verify the "Environment variables" listed at http://www.imagemagick.org/script/resources.php   Also check this link  http://drupal.org/node/217960

Answer (score 41):

This is an old question, but the current solution with ImageMagick 7 is to use the "magick" command in place of "convert".

Comment: It has also been mentioned [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=29582).

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question, but I encountered this problem today, and this is my solution in Windows 7.

Windows convert.exe is located in folder `C:\Windows\System32`, so you have to modify the Windows PATH variable by putting the ImageMagick path (for example `C:\Libs\ImageMagick-6.8.8-4`) before the path that loads `System32` (ie. `%SystemRoot%\System32`).

This will cause all ImageMagick executables to take priority over any similarly named system executables, which should do what you want but may cause unexpected behaviour.

Also, when you want to use the system convert.exe, you'll have to specify the full pathname such as `C:\Windows\System32\convert.exe`.

Answer (score 5):

Renaming the ImageMagick `convert.exe` worked well for me.

I didn't like using full path each time, and changing the system PATH variable isn't possible for me on the work PC.

After renaming `convert.exe` to `imgconvert.exe`, no other changes were needed. You could now use the new command anywhere from the command line without it being confused with the intrinsic Windows file system `convert`

---

**Edit**: As of version 7.0, the command is now `magick.exe`, which no longer clashes with any native windows commands. So downloading the latest version if possible should solve the problem as well.

Comment: I agree. I wouldn't change the PATH variable to place non-system executables before system executables, because programs might depend on it. If you don't want to rename either, consider making a symbolic link like so: mklink "C:\IM6-Path\convert-im6.exe" "C:\IM6-Path\convert.exe".

Comment: Yes.  Every other solution requires extra work (typing the whole path), or some how mucking with system config.  This is straight forward and simple.

Comment: where is(was) `convert.exe`?

Answer (score 1):

In powershell you can run this: `$env:Path = "C:\path-to-convert\;$env:Path"`

Now the imagemagick convert exe gets found because it comes first in the path.