# itext pdf to image convert

Tags: java, image, pdf, itext

I my task is convert pdf  to image,I able to convert rgb based color model pdf to image but i was not able to convert(image type device cmyk)
I used itext api for read the pdf file and get  the  pagesize and used bufferimage to convert the image.I dont know how do find
out the solution.plese help me out.

Code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Transparency;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ColorConvertOp;
import java.awt.image.ColorModel;
import java.awt.image.PixelGrabber;
import java.awt.image.Raster;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

import org.apache.pdfbox.PDFReader;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPatternPainter;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.sun.pdfview.PDFFile;
import com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage;

import java.awt.color.ColorSpace;
import java.awt.font.GlyphVector;

import sun.awt.SunHints;
import sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D;
import sun.font.GlyphList;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;

public class PdfToMultiImage {


    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("HEEEEEEEEE::::::::::::");
        // private String sourceDir;
        File sourceFile = new File("/home/PDF_Clipping/tp_cmyk.pdf");
        // private String destinationDir;
        File destinationFile = new File("/home/testImage/page_0003");
        String fileName = sourceFile.getName().replace(".pdf", "");

        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(sourceFile, "r");
        FileChannel channel = raf.getChannel();
        ByteBuffer buf = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0,
                channel.size());
        PDFFile pdf = new PDFFile(buf);

        System.out.println("Total Pages: " + pdf.getNumPages());
        int pageNumber = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < pdf.getNumPages(); i++) {
              PDFPage page = pdf.getPage(i+1);

            // image dimensions
            int width = 1200;
            int height = 1400;
            // create the image

            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, (int) page.getBBox()
                    .getWidth(), (int) page.getBBox().getHeight());

            BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height,
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);


            Image image = page.getImage(width, height, rect, null, true, true);

            ColorSpace colorSpace ;
        int a=  bufferedImage.getType();
        System.out.println(a);


            Graphics2D bufImageGraphics = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
            bufImageGraphics.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

            File imageFile = new File(destinationFile + "pdfImg" + i + ".png");

            ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", imageFile);
            pageNumber++;
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: I would have done it with imagemagick using profiles to convert from cmyk to rgb and the other way around. Run Imagemagick in terminal och use java process to send command that you read from outputstream.

Comment: I tried imagemagick but it was not work for me I'm not able to do further process here is tthe link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025515/converting-a-multi-page-pdf-to-multiple-pages-using-a-single-command