# ImageMagick's Convert for EPS to JPEG not being called properly

Tags: java, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

M primary goal is to take in a series of .eps files and convert them to .jpg using ImageMagick and GhostScript. I have both ImageMagick and GhostScript installed in a Windows environment. I am referencing ImageMagick's convert command using Process in java with no luck. Using Window's `cmd` tool, I successfully converted an EPS to JPEG by navigating to *C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16* and using the following command:

```
convert Raw\R_GiftcardSizeNew3x5.eps Converted\R_GiftcardSizeNew3x5.jpg
```

In Java, I use almost the exact same command in the following code:

```
public void convertEPStoJPG()
{   //commands
    ArrayList<String> cmds = new ArrayList<String>();
    //absolute file paths of eps files retrieved using a helper method
    ArrayList<String> filePaths = this.getFilePaths();
    //beginning cmd line calls
    cmds.add("cmd.exe");
    cmds.add("/c");
    cmds.add("cd C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16\\");

    for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.size(); i++)
    {
        //conversion calls
        String tempPath = filePaths.get(i);
        //shortening path name
        tempPath = tempPath.substring(tempPath.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1, tempPath.length());

        //adding command of "convert Raw\\image.eps Converted\\image.jpg"
        cmds.add("convert \\Naked Wines\\Raw\\" + tempPath + " \\Naked Wines\\Converted\\" + 
        tempPath.substring(0,tempPath.length() - 3) + "jpg");
    }
    //building process with commands
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmds);
    Process process;
    try {    
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        //executing commands
        process = pb.start();

        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while (true) {
            line = r.readLine();
            if (line == null) { break; }
            //print output from command execution
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

where my files im trying to grab are *C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16\Naked Wines\Raw*
and the destination I am converting to is *C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16\Naked Wines\Converted*.

I get an error stating *"The system cannot find the path specified"*. Looking at previously answered questions such as [How to override Windows' convert command by ImageMagick's one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481573/how-to-override-windows-convert-command-by-imagemagicks-convert-command), people suggest you have to override Windows `convert` command. Would this be the cause of error, or is there something I am missing? I'm fairly new to ImageMagick and might have missed or misunderstood something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up approaching this problem in a different way using Im4Java, a pure-java interface to the ImageMagick commandline. I installed the libraries via http://im4java.sourceforge.net/#download. Here is my code for converting eps to jpg:

```
public void convertESPtoJPG()
{
    //initialize ImageMagick operation
    IMOperation op = new IMOperation();

    //setting my path allows us to use ImageMagicks "convert" vs. Windows "convert"
    String myPath="C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16";
    ProcessStarter.setGlobalSearchPath(myPath);

    op.addImage(); //in
    op.addImage(); //out
    ConvertCmd cmd = new ConvertCmd();

    //filter out files for eps files, and load the files using included FilenameLoader
    ExtensionFilter filter = new ExtensionFilter("eps");
    FilenameLoader  loader = new FilenameLoader(filter);
    List<String> files = loader.loadFilenames("C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.8.9- 
Q16\\NakedWines\\Raw\\");

    //what we plan on converting our eps files to
    FilenamePatternResolver resolver = new FilenamePatternResolver("%P/%f.jpg");

    //iterate through loaded files
    for (String img: files)
    {
        try {
            //execute our convert commands
            cmd.run(op,img,resolver.createName(img));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I found this method to be much easier to understand and more forward as well.