# Error: Stream yields empty buffer using gm on nodejs (Windows)

Tags: node.js, windows, gm

When I try to execute this simple example of code using gm and nodejs on Windows:

```
var gm = require('gm').subClass({imageMagick: true}); 
gm(50, 50, '#000F')
    .setFormat('img') 
    .fill('black') 
    .drawCircle( 50, 50, 60, 60 ) 
    .toBuffer(function( error, buffer ) {
        if( error ) { console.log( error ); return; }
        console.log( 'success: ' + buffer.length ); 
    } 
);
```

I get the error:

`[Error: Stream yields empty buffer]`

Why is this error happining and how can I solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is with:

```
.setFormat('img')
```

Try setting it to something like `'png'` or `'jpeg'`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was to copy the `magick` program from its directory to `convert.exe` name and then the above code snippet started to work. (It might be that [convert program of windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481573/how-to-override-windows-convert-command-by-imagemagicks-one) is tried to be used within gm, but even supplying appPath didn't help. )