# Grabbing a screenshot from Twitch with Python

Tags: python, screenshot, python-3.5, twitch

Right now, I'm starting a Python project which is supposed to take a screenshot of selected twitch channels, modify those screenshots and put them on a GUI. The GUI shouldn't be a problem, but I'm having problems with the screenshots.
I've found 2 resources to deal with the twitch communication: the python-twitch package and a script called ttvsnap (https://github.com/chfoo/ttvsnap).
The package was no help to me, because I didn't find anything related to screenshots. The script looked promising, but I encountered some problems:

According to the creator, ttvsnap periodically takes screenshots of a twitch stream and puts them in a selected directory.
<s>If I try to start the script, I'm getting this error:</s>

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
    File "ttvsnap.py", line 13, in <module>
        import requests  
ImportError: No module named 'requests'
```

Erasing "import requests" from the script allows me to run it, but the script then has a problem with selecting a directory. To run the script, I'm supposed to write:

```
Python ttvsnap.py 'streamname here' 'directory here'
```

The example directory from the creator was './screenshot/', but with that input, I'm getting the following error (maybe because I'm on Windows?):

```
Output directory specified is not valid.
```

Trying a directory like C:\DevFiles\Screenshots give me the following error:

```
Invalid drive specification. ###Translated this line since I'm using a German OS
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ttvsnap.py", line 176, in <module>
    main()
  File "ttvsnap.py", line 46, in main
    subprocess.check_call(['convert', '-version'])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 584, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['convert', '-version']' returned non-zero exit status 4
```

Any idea on how to get it to run or a different resource to use would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to `pip install requests`? It's not part of the standard library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium can be handy for navigating a site and taking screenshots.

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Fleshed out an example that should do what you need.
Gist link as well : 
https://gist.github.com/ryantownshend/6449c4d78793f015f3adda22a46f1a19

```
"""
basic example.

Dirt simple example of using selenium to screenshot a site.

Defaults to using local Firefox install.
Can be setup to use PhantomJS

http://phantomjs.org/download.html

This example will run in both python 2 and 3
"""
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


def main():
    """the main function."""
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    # driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    driver.get("http://google.com")
    # assert "Python" in driver.title
    elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
    elem.clear()
    elem.send_keys("cats")
    elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    # give the query result time to load
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "resultStats"))
    )

    # take the screenshot
    pwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    driver.save_screenshot(os.path.join(pwd, 'cats.png'))
    driver.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: for my purposes, are there any requisites to selenium (like ImageMagick) or am I good to go once I installed the package?

Comment: Updated the post, with an example for you.

Comment: thanks, the example works with PhantomJS for me. However, I'm new to Python so I don't fully understand how you set the destination of the screenshot. Is the "__ file __" variable referring to the file that contains your script itself?

Comment: Exactly that. Then from there you can use the os.path libraries to build a valid local path.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't remove things from an open source project you are trying to use.

Instead, install the missing packages,

`pip install requests` if you have a problem with that maybe you don't have `pip`, so just install it.

Or use this `python.exe -m pip install requests`.

---

This error `Output directory specified is not valid.` is due to this line:

```
if not os.path.isdir(args.output_dir):
    sys.exit('Output directory specified is not valid.')
```

It generally means that the **directory doesn't exist**.

---

As for the last error, it cannot execute the command `convert`:

```
Invalid drive specification. ###Translated this line since I'm using a German OS
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ttvsnap.py", line 176, in <module>
    main()
  File "ttvsnap.py", line 46, in main
    subprocess.check_call(['convert', '-version'])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 584, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['convert', '-version']' returned non-zero exit status 4
```

It just means that you don't have `Imagemagick` installed. You can install it by **downloading** the right installer for your architecture here: [Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php)

Then install it with these options ticked:
[image]

Then try and make sure that the `convert` command executes from your terminal. If not, follow this instruction:

> Lastly you have to set **MAGICK_HOME** environment variable to the path of
> ImageMagick (e.g. C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.7.7-Q16). You can set
> it in Computer ‣ Properties ‣ Advanced system settings ‣ Advanced ‣
> Environment Variables....
>
> [source](https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.2.4/guide/install.html)

Comment: Installed requests, now I don't have to erase it from the script anymore, but I'm still getting the same error messages like I did before

Comment: @Hillburn have you created the folder in question? Does it currently exist?

Comment: @Hillburn Try `python3 ttvsnap.py verycoolstreamer ./screenshots/`, but make sure the directory `screenshots` exist on the current directory where you are running the script.

Comment: I wrote 'Python ttvsnap.py SaltyBet ./screens/' with a folder called screens inside the ttvsnap folder, but I still get the last error I posted in my question.

Comment: @Hillburn I updated my answer. Its because you don't have the `ImageMagick` installed.

Comment: Followed your instructions, still getting the same error. Does ImageMagick support Windows 10?

Comment: @Hillburn did you try to run `convert` command via your terminal if it works? (Just to make sure that `convert` is available). The script should then work if the `convert` command works manually if executed through the terminal.

Comment: typing convert in my terminal results in "A file system must be specified."

Comment: @Hillburn see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481573/how-to-override-windows-convert-command-by-imagemagicks-one

Comment: According to the link, I have to put ImageMagick before System32 in the PATH environment variable to override "convert". But "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.2-Q16" is already at the top of the list.

Comment: @Hillburn sorry man, that is all I can help. You'll have to find out how to install ImageMagick properly for windows. I myself don't use windows for development.